# Can't create two projects using .NET Framework and .NET Core in Rider for MacOS?

Tags: asp.net, .net, rider

I'm pulling my hair here. I can't seem to run two projects under the same solution where one uses .NET Core 6 and the other uses .NET Framework 4.7.2

I have set the `MSBuild` to Auto detect and this allows the .NET Framework project to run, but for some reason the .NET Core project appears with missing dependencies (can't read the symbol System) and then I get this error as well:

`MSBuild cannot find TargetFramework assemblies for .NETFramework,Version=v6.0.`

If I change the MSBuild, then .NET Core works and .NET Framework doesn't. Can't seem to get them to work together simultaneously. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does [this](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/core/porting/project-structure) help you?